# Android does not show keyboard although set in code

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I have an android app that works fine, apart from that in one part of it the keyboard - **although opened with the following code** - does not appear:

```
View.OnFocusChangeListener vof = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }
    }
};

// ...

final TextView input = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
input.setOnFocusChangeListener(vof);
input.requestFocus();
```

Everything I could find on other help pages only came up with this solution, which did not work when I tried to use it on my Samsung Galaxy S2.

Comment: are you sure the onFocusChange is called?

Comment: @njzk2 I am sure it is - the android sdk / adt for eclipse added this method automatically and I do not expect this to be wrong. Also, this code works for another textedit in this app.

Comment: I found the solution now... see my edit

Comment: +1 for posting your own solution and not just forgetting about this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem - the XML layout asked for the focus before I set the listener so that onFocusChange was never called:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/answer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="175dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/question"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

When I removed the <requestFocus /> part it worked as I wanted it to.

Comment: Note that editing the original question with an answer (even if you asked the question) is the correct way to propose answers on StackOverflow.  If you find an answer to your own question, you should post it as an answer, so others can vote up/down on it.  If you feel that the answer solved your issue, then you can accept it by checking the green checkbox on the left underneath the vote mechanism for the answer.